# message": "Invalid URL (PATCH /v1/completions)",

Tags: automation, theta360

Again and again I am getting this errror in Automation A360.I am new to this Please help me out

{ "error": { "message": "Invalid URL (PATCH /v1/completions)", "type": "invalid_request_error", "param": null, "code": null }

{
"error": {
"message": "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from [https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys."](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.%22),
"type": "invalid_request_error",
"param": null,
"code": null
}
}

Answer (score -1):

The error messages you are encountering seem to be related to the API calls you are making to Automation A360. Let's break down each error message:

**Error 1#** Invalid URL (PATCH /v1/completions)

This error suggests that the URL you are using for the PATCH request to the "/v1/completions" endpoint is incorrect or invalid. Double-check the URL you are using and ensure that it is correctly formatted and points to the intended resource. You can check the swagger list or documentation for the same.

**Error2#** You didn't provide an API key...

This error indicates that you have not provided the required API key for authentication. To access the Automation A360 API, you need to include your API key in the request. You can include your API key in the "Authorization" header of your request using Bearer authentication. The header should be in the following format:

```
"Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Ensure that you have obtained an API key for Automation A360 from the OpenAI platform. If you haven't generated an API key yet, you can do so at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.

Comment: Hello Sir I have generated the api key and added in the authorization also but still I am getting the error.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the header configuration if possible?

Comment: Sir Can I share on LinkedIn here I am not able to add an image